# How long will reconstituted beans last in the refrigerator?

Tags: beans

Dried beans.  Soaked overnight.  Drained.  How long can I keep them in the refrigerator before use?

Comment: Duplicate of [How long can I store soaked beans before cooking?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13340/42797)

Comment: @AlanMunn Actually, the question you refer to asks about length of soaking and storing in water.  I've indicated that the beans were re-hydrated, then drained and refrigerated.  I believe the questions are different.  Also, I am not sure that I buy the info in the comment that suggests draining "gets one an extra day or so."  My question seeks a more definitive answer.

Comment: Well like most "how long can I keep X" questions, the answers are rarely definitive. The answer in the linked question covers the issue fairly well. I've kept soaked beans in the fridge for a couple of days without a problem, as I'm sure many here have. So at best you may get a range of times, probably most well under 5 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's not so much about safe. As indicated under 5 days is probably safe for uncooked veg protein. That's what we use in the restaurant world as general safety rules of thumb. 2 days for meat, three days for starches, 5 days for beans.

However, you may decide that the beans have significantly softened and may no longer be suitable for your application. It depends on what you are doing. Beans in a chili (I know chili doesn't have beans in it) you want to have some firmness, beans in a burrito medium firmness and beans for a bean dip or refried, well you want pretty mushy.

So safety wise you are probably just fine, but make sure your application warrants how soft the beans may become.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use them up within a couple day, just to be on the safe side. Make sure that you're storing them in an air tight container, that usually helps keep it fresher.