# Shelf life and preservation of home soaked and drained black beans

Tags: storage-lifetime, food-preservation, beans

I am looking to see if I can avoid store bought tin of black beans for our Mexican recipes, we typically decide suddenly to make a Mexican dish and usually dont have soaked beans handy.

Is it possible to preserve home soaked and drained black beans? What would be a typical shelf life.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/how-long-can-i-store-soaked-beans-before-cooking

Comment: Instead of storing soaked beans, I just cook them without too many strong flavorings, and then put them in a zip top freezer bag in reasonable sized portions and freeze it.  (I think I first saw the recommendation from Food Network's Melissa d'Arabian).  But around me, dry bean prices have been going up faster than canned bean prices in the last decade or so, so the cost savings vs convenience as compared to canned beans has gone down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve your beans more than a couple of days, you can either pressure can or freeze them.  With either option, the beans will remain safe for a year or more (as long as they are stored at appropriate temperature, and the seal remains intact for pressure canned).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to store them in a food container in the freezer at -18°C for at least 3 months.